# Segmentation fault upon input with getline()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a simple program that takes in the users input, then prints it out. It's to keep doing this until the user types `"done"`.

When I run the code below, I input "01", then get a `Segmentation Fault ( core dumped )`.

I think this has something to do with `getline()`, but I don't know.  I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me why it's not working and how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

char* line;
size_t size ;
size = 100;
char* done;
done = "done";
printf("0");
while ( strcmp(line, "done") != 0 ) { 
    printf("1");
    getline(&line, &size, stdin); 
    printf("2");
    printf("%s\n", line); 
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you just have a pointer that is pointing to nothing (actually garbage):

```
char* line;
```

From the man page for [getline()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline):

> If *lineptr is NULL, then getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line, which should be freed by the user program. (In this case, the value in *n is ignored.)
>
> Alternatively, before calling getline(), *lineptr can contain a pointer to a malloc(3)-allocated buffer *n bytes in size. If the buffer is not large enough to hold the line, getline() resizes it with realloc(3), updating *lineptr and *n as necessary.
>
> In either case, on a successful call, *lineptr and *n will be updated to reflect the buffer address and allocated size respectively.

So, note that you **cannot** use a stack-allocated buffer for getline.

The easier way to do this, is to initialize `line` to NULL and let `getline` handle the allocation for you:

```
char* line = NULL;
int size = 0;
getline(&line, &size, stdin);   // line and size are updated with buffer addr and size.
//...
free(line);
```

Comment: You cannot pass a non-`malloc`ed object to `getline`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html *Before calling getline, you should place in *lineptr the address of a buffer *n bytes long, allocated with malloc*. The rationale for this is `getline` can `realloc` the object if the buffer size is not sufficient to hold the line.

Answer (score 5):

You are not allocating memory for:

```
char* line;
```

`line` is an invalid pointer before it points to a valid object. Use `malloc` to allocate memory, e.g., `line =  malloc(size);`

Answer (score 1):

```
char* line = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
```

When no more necessary remember to free the memory:

```
free(line);
```

Comment: `On success, getline() and getdelim() return the number of characters read, including the delimiter character, but not including the terminating null byte.` As stated in the quote from the accepted answer, the integer passed to `getline()` will be updated with the new size if the memory pointed to is `realloc()`ed